# Why does order matter when using "data" and "formula" keyword arguments?

Tags: r, plot, arguments

In **R**, why is it that the order of the `data` and `formula` keywords matters when plotting? I thought that with *named arguments* order *isn't* supposed to matter...

For an example of what I mean, check out this code:

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)

# Correct formulation (apparently):
plot(formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age, data=menarche)

# In contrast, note how the following returns an error:
plot(data=menarche, formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age)
```

Is this just a quirk of the `plot` function or is this behavior exhibited in other functions as well?

Comment: `graphics:::plot.default(data=menarche, formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age)` vs `graphics:::plot.formula(data=menarche, formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age)`

Comment: @rawr right; it is S3 dispatch working on the arguments and dispatching to different methods not the ordering that is causing the error. However, the first should be `graphics:::plot.data.frame` as `traceback()` shows it is this method that is actually being called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is related to S3 methods for the S3 generic `plot()`. S3 dispatches methods based on the first argument however the exact functioning is complicated because `formula` is allowed as a special exception from the usual generic arguments of `plot()`, which are `x` and `y` plus `...`:

```
> args(plot)
function (x, y, ...) 
NULL
```

Hence what happens in the first case is that the `plot.formula()` method is run because the first argument supplied is a formula and this matches the arguments of `plot.formula()`

```
> args(graphics:::plot.formula)
function (formula, data = parent.frame(), ..., subset, ylab = varnames[response], 
    ask = dev.interactive()) 
NULL
```

for example:

```
> debugonce(graphics:::plot.formula)
> plot(formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age, data=menarche)
debugging in: plot.formula(formula = Menarche/Total ~ Age, data = menarche)
debug: {
    m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
[...omitted...]
```

In contrast, when you call `plot(data=menarche, formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age)`, the first argument is a data frame and hence the `graphics:::plot.data.frame` method is called:

```
> plot(data=menarche, formula=Menarche/Total ~ Age)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
> traceback()
3: is.data.frame(x)
2: plot.data.frame(data = menarche, formula = Menarche/Total ~ Age)
1: plot(data = menarche, formula = Menarche/Total ~ Age)
```

but because that method expects an argument `x`, which you didn't supply, you get the error about missing `x`.

So in a sense, the ordering of named arguments doesn't and shouldn't matter but when S3 generics are in play method dispatch kicks in first to decide which method to pass the arguments on to and then the arguments supplied - not the ordering - is what will often catch you out, especially when mixing the `formula` methods with other non-`formula` methods.

Comment: **+1**. I don't know how you were able to do all that so quickly. In fact, it makes me wonder how I wasted so much time looking for the answer in the first place. Now, if you'll excuse me, I have to process all of it...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien It is calling `plot()` -> `plot.formula()` -> `plot.default()`; That seems to interpret `HERRINGS` as passing `Total` to `x` and `Age` to `y` hence you get an actual plot and then `HERRINGS` remains in the call as a formula hence the multiple warnings. To understand exactly what is going on we'd have to study the steps in `plot.formula` to see how it is interpreting the formula or just pulling data from `data = menarche`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - Got it, thanks. Things go off track in `plot.formula()`'s call to `stats::model.frame.default`, which -- without any formula to guide it -- just returns a model frame with columns "Age", "Total", and "Menarche". (*With* a formula argument to direct it, it would produce a two-column model frame with columns "Menarche/Total" and "Age"). Later on, `plot.formula()` extracts the first column of the model frame `mf`, passing it along to  `plot.default()`'s `y` argument and the rest of the model frame to the `x` argument.

Comment: (For the record, in a since-deleted comment, I had asked Gavin if he knew why a call to `plot(HERRINGS=Menarche/Total ~ Age, data=menarche)` gives the results that it does.)

Comment: +1 @JoshO'Brien that was what I thought might be happening given the way the variables were assigned to `x` and `y`, but I didn't have chance to check it myself as lunch was very much calling me :-)