# Using formula as a keyword argument (named parameter) with wilcox.test in R

Tags: r, formula, keyword-argument

Why do I get an error when I use the "formula" as a keyword argument with `wilcox.test` in R? The docs say that it has a "formula" parameter.

```
df = data.frame(A=rnorm(10), D=sample(c('p','q'), 10, replace=T))
wilcox.test(data=df, A~D)
wilcox.test(data=df, formula=A~D)

> df = data.frame(A=rnorm(10), D=sample(c('p','q'), 10, replace=T))
> wilcox.test(data=df, A~D)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  A by D
W = 13, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> wilcox.test(data=df, formula=A~D)
Error in wilcox.test.default(data = df, formula = A ~ D) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Interesting - it doesn't complain if it's first - `wilcox.test(formula=A~D, data=df)` or if you call it explicitly - `stats:::wilcox.test.formula(data=df, formula=A~D)` I'm not super confident about these sorts of things, but I think it is because the `wilcox.test` function is dispatching to either `wilcox.test.default` or `wilcox.test.formula` based on the first argument to the function call.

Comment: Yeah I think it is because of the default `S3` methods function. Similar post on `plot` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893878/why-does-order-matter-when-using-data-and-formula-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arguments are not in the correct order.

```
> wilcox.test(formula=A~D, data=df)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  A by D
W = 13, p-value = 0.6667
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

42- pointed out that I was incorrect about the purpose of formula arguments, since without the optional data argument the data objects would be inherited from the environment. The function chooses the default method instead of the formula method because it does not see a formula argument in the first argument location. Otherwise, argument order would not matter.

Comment: Keyword arguments can generally go in any order in R

Comment: The formula argument is NOT the data argument. Agree with Marius about what should be happening, but the more typical convention in methods that are intended to decode a formula is for the formula argument to be first, since dispatch is on the first argument. See `lm.formula` or `xtabs.formula`. The examples from `ggplot` functions cannot be considered canonical since they came much later than base or stats functions in the evolution of R.

Comment: @Marius while this is true, in this particular case the formula needs to come first for the formula method to get called instead of the default, as 42- has said. If there was no formula method for this function it would not matter.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is getting confused because the generic and the formula method use different names for the formula argument, namely, `x` and `formula`.  Normally when writing S3 methods the argument names of the methods should be consistent with the generic.

```
> args(wilcox.test)
function (x, ...) 
NULL

> args(stats:::wilcox.test.formula)
function (formula, data, subset, na.action, ...) 
NULL
```